# network lag when other computer is off

Tags: networking, wake-on-lan, lag, latency

Sometimes when several computers that are on the same network(plugged into the very same network switch) and one of them is *off*, the network gets random lags(up to 400ms). Just to highlight: the NIC of the suspicious system does not go off(just like if it listens for incoming Wake On Lan packets). If one either unplugs the network cable out of it or the power cable, the lag immediately goes off and the network behaves normally.

I've seen this problem on several systems and different networks and have no idea of that is going on, so looks like it is not connected to some special hardware as motherboards and BIOS vendors differ widely. Disabling Wake On Lan or physically unplugging the suspicious system does the job.

Have searched for it for several hours on WWW with no luck, but I don't believe it's a common issue. Do you have any explanation?

Looks like the NIC of the mentioned system somehow affects the switch in which it is plugged in. How to debug the issue? Should one just tcpdump the pakets, or should more low level tools be used like monitoring ARP to dig into it?

Comment: As WOL works on layer two it would probably be sufficient. For a start you could have a look at what data the sleeping device is sending (if any).

Answer (score 0):

## Investigate with Wireshark

[Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) will let you capture all traffic being generated by that NIC's MAC address, which will include Link Layer stuff life ARPs.

Your issue might be related to [Connected Standby](http://www.howtogeek.com/189224/):

> When in Connected Standby mode, your PC will listen for notifications
>   and wake up regularly to fetch new emails, update live tiles, and
>   perform other similar tasks.

Comment: It happens both with Windows 7 installed and Windows XP. I won't be surprised if this will happen to linux too. Also, this feature seems to be listening to *incoming* data, right? Not generating outgoing